# PHP include binary-safe?

Tags: php, output-buffering

I faced with an issue with php buffer like that

```
ob_start();
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
include "Death_Valley.mp3";
//header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='Death_Valley.mp3'");
echo ob_get_clean();
```

If I use **include** instead of **file_get_contents** (which is binary safe) I got an error

> Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}'

Just for self-education is it really non-binary-safe issue?
Or I miss something with an understanding of **include** function?

Comment: When in doubt, consult the manual. And the manual states `The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file`. Keyword: **evaluates**.

Answer (score 5):

well, no, it's not binary safe. if it comes across the bytes `<=` or `<?` or `<?php` , it will corrupt the download.

furthermore, if hackers are able to upload their own files to your server, you're looking at a remote code execution vulnerability (injecting php code to mp3 files. Imgur or imageshack got hacked due to this very mistake, some idiot developer decided the best way was to include('image.jpg'); )

the correct way to do what you want is

```
readfile("Death_Valley.mp3");
```

and drop the ob_start(), that will fill the entire file in memory before giving it out to the user, which is both slow and memory hungry

and final thought: if you're using apache/lighthttpd/nginx, you should probably check out X-sendfile (lighthttpd/apache) or X-Accel-Redirect (nginx), which will scale much better than anything php-based (at least in Zend's PHP. maybe it doesn't matter in HHVM php, idk)